# Structuring Rails Layouts in a nested way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I can't find a clean way to do this but it's a common case so it must exist. This is about rails 5.1 Views and Layouts.

I have a application.html.erb layout that includes the various  tags and also various tags I want at the end of each page. In the middle is a `<%= yield %>`, as usual.

I have two controllers, courses_controller.rb and students_controller.rb.

I would like all the views that come from each of those two controllers to have a common html pre- and post- section, so again, I reach for a layout, for example called courses.html.erb and students.html.erb, both in the layouts directory.

However now the controllers will use *just* those controller specific layouts and not use the top level application.html.erb layout. This is as specced and as expected, but for my case it leads to problems.

What I want is that application.html.erb sets the pattern for all pages, and that within that the layouts/courses.html.erb and layouts/students.html.erb set the pattern for the inside part of the resulting html.

I believe this is a very natural case but all the solutions I've come up with or read about seem to be ugly and kludgy.